# Could not deduce (Eq a), adding Eq to typeclass

Tags: haskell

I'm quite new to Haskell, and I ran into this bug when trying to compile [Frag](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Frag).

```
src/AFRPVectorSpace.hs:51:25:
    Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from a use of `/='
    from the context (VectorSpace v a)
      bound by the class declaration for `VectorSpace'
      at src/AFRPVectorSpace.hs:(32,1)-(53,23)
    Possible fix:
      add (Eq a) to the context of
        the class declaration for `VectorSpace'
    In the expression: nv /= 0
    In the expression:
      if nv /= 0 then v ^/ nv else error "normalize: zero vector"
    In an equation for `normalize':
        normalize v
          = if nv /= 0 then v ^/ nv else error "normalize: zero vector"
          where
              nv = norm v
```

Relevent code:

```
class Floating a => VectorSpace v a | v -> a where
    zeroVector   :: v
    (*^)         :: a -> v -> v
    (^/)         :: v -> a -> v
    negateVector :: v -> v
    (^+^)        :: v -> v -> v
    (^-^)        :: v -> v -> v
    dot          :: v -> v -> a
    norm     :: v -> a
    normalize    :: v -> v

    v ^/ a = (1/a) *^ v

    negateVector v = (-1) *^ v

    v1 ^-^ _ = v1 ^+^ v1 -- (negateVector v2)

    norm v = sqrt (v `dot` v)

    normalize v = if nv /= 0 then v ^/ nv else error "normalize: zero vector"
        where
        nv = norm v
```

My first guess is that I need to add a `Deriving Eq` or something of that sort, but I'm not sure what exactly I need to do.

Comment: I'd argue that you don't really want an `Eq` constraint for floating types, it's usually somewhat troublesome. I'd rather add `class (Num f) => TestZero f where { isZero :: f->Bool }`, and then `instance (Eq f, Num f) => instance TestZero f where { isZero = (==0) }`.

Comment: There is not necessarily a way to convert from `0` into the vector type `v`.  However, changing `if nv /= 0 then` to `if dot v v /= 0 then` should do the trick, because `a` is a numeric type.

Answer (score 6):

I'd guess you'd need to have `class (Eq a,Floating a) => VectorSpace v a | v -> a` if you want to use `/=` for `a` in your default implementations.

Second alternative is to remove `normalize` from the class and make it an ordinary function instead.

Third alternative is to add the constraint to the type of the `normalize`, making it `Eq a => v -> v`.

Comment: Only `normalize` needs to be removed

Comment: If you want to keep `normalize` in the class, you can change its type signature to `normalize :: Eq a => v -> v`.

Answer (score 5):

Prior to ghc 7.4.1, the `Num a` class had `Eq a` constraint, so any `Num a` also had `Eq a`. `Floating a` has a constraint `Num a`, so therefore anything `Floating a` was also `Eq a`.

However, this changed with 7.4.1, where the `Eq a` constraint (as well as the `Show a` constraint) was removed from the `Num` class. This is why the code isn't working anymore.

So the solution to the problem is exactly what aleator gave: Add the `Eq a` constraint explicitly to the `VectorSpace` class.

Alternatively, you may want to download an older version of ghc (eg 6.8 based on the wiki notes). That version should compile the program without any changes. Then you can update the code to get it working with a newer version of ghc if you so desire.

Answer (score 1):

*This isn't an answer to your question (which has already been answered), but since it's not easy to paste blocks of code into comments, I'll add it as an "answer".*

You might prefer to use type families instead of functional dependencies. Type families allow you to do everything you can do with functional dependencies, plus a whole lot more. Here's one way to write your code using type families. It looks very similar to your original code, except that your type variable `a` has been replaced with a "call" to a *type function* `Metric v` (the best name I could think of offhand.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

class Floating (Metric v) => VectorSpace v where
    type Metric v
    zeroVector   :: v
    (*^)         :: Metric v -> v -> v
    (^/)         :: v -> Metric v -> v
    negateVector :: v -> v
    (^+^)        :: v -> v -> v
    (^-^)        :: v -> v -> v
    dot          :: v -> v -> Metric v
    norm     :: v -> Metric v
    normalize    :: Eq (Metric v) => v -> v

    v ^/ a = (1/a) *^ v

    negateVector v = (-1) *^ v

    v1 ^-^ _ = v1 ^+^ v1 -- (negateVector v2)

    norm v = sqrt (v `dot` v)

    normalize v = if nv /= 0 then v ^/ nv else error "normalize: zero vector"
        where
        nv = norm v
```

Here are some useful links:

- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families
- http://nattermorphisms.blogspot.ie/2008/10/2-minute-intro-to-associated-types-type.html
- http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-February/055890.html

Comment: I would call the associated type `Scalar` (or `ScalarOf`), I think that's the mathematically more usual way of saying 'the field this vector space is over'. Thanks for the haskell-cafe link, which answered a question about back-and-forth TFs!